# SQL query to merge consecutive dates and ignore non-consecutive ones

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help as I'm not so good with SQL statements...

I have the following table in the Database:

```
+------+------------+------------+
| E_ID |  FromDate  |   ToDate   |
+------+------------+------------+
|  555 | 2012-01-01 | 2012-12-31 |
|  555 | 2013-01-01 | 2013-12-31 |
|  555 | 2014-01-01 | 2014-04-30 |
|  555 | 2014-05-01 | 2014-08-15 |
|  555 | 2014-08-16 | 2014-12-31 |
|  555 | 2015-01-01 | 2015-06-25 |
|  555 | 2015-07-01 | 2015-12-31 |
+------+------------+------------+
```

I want to merge consecutive dates, grouped by year, after playing a little I came to this query:

```
select  E_ID
       ,FromDate = MIN(FromDate)
       ,ToDate = MAX(ToDate)
from TbTest
group by E_ID
        ,DATEPART(YEAR,FromDate)
        ,DATEPART(YEAR,ToDate)
```

And the result is almost what I want:

```
+------+------------+------------+
| E_ID |  FromDate  |   ToDate   |
+------+------------+------------+
|  555 | 2012-01-01 | 2012-12-31 |
|  555 | 2013-01-01 | 2013-12-31 |
|  555 | 2014-01-01 | 2014-12-31 |
|  555 | 2015-01-01 | 2015-12-31 |
+------+------------+------------+
```

This is almost perfect. The problem here is that in the dates for year 2015 we have a overlap:

```
|  555 | 2015-01-01 | 2015-06-25 |
|  555 | 2015-07-01 | 2015-12-31 |
```

So instead of the FromDate being 2015-06-26, it is 2015-07-01, so we have a "gap" of 6 days. For those specific cases, I want to split them, so the result that I want is this:

```
+------+------------+-------------+
| E_ID |  FromDate  |   ToDate    |
+------+------------+-------------+
|  555 | 2012-01-01 | 2012-12-31  |
|  555 | 2013-01-01 | 2013-12-31  |
|  555 | 2014-01-01 | 2014-12-31  |
|  555 | 2015-01-01 | 2015-06-25  |
|  555 | 2015-07-01 | 2015-12-31  |
+------+------------+-------------+
```

In small words, I need trully consecutive dates to be merged without a day missing.

PS: I'm thinking now and ToDate can be something like 9999-12-31 sometimes, so I my group by year is actually not correct...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you ever need a "gap free" list, it could be better only to store the "ToDate" and calculate the duration backward. In your case, if you don't want to get an extremely slow and complicated query, I'd think of filling your gaps with dummy-periods.

Comment: This is a lot easier if there is always at max one overlap at a time... is there more than that?  Hint, use recursive CTE

Comment: This might be one of those rare cases where a cursor will actually perform better than a set-based query.

Comment: @TabAlleman - That was true before CTEs

Comment: If you use SQL Server 2012+ use `LAG` or `LEAD` functions. If you use previous versions of SQL Server use cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry because I haven't the time to test the code below but I think the idea is here.

```
with aggr as
(
select  E_ID,
        FromDate,
        ToDate,
        lev = 0
from TbTest
UNION ALL
select  T.E_ID,
       A.FromDate,
       T.ToDate,
       lev = A.lev + 1 
from TbTest T
        inner join aggr A
        on T.e_ID = A.E_ID  AND datediff(day,A.Todate,T.FromDate) = 1 
        AND DATEPART(YEAR,A.TODate) = DATEPART(YEAR,T.FromDate)
)

select E_ID, FromDate, ToDate from aggr
EXCEPT
Select AG1.E_ID, AG1.FromDate, AG1.ToDate
from aggr AG1
 inner join aggr AG2
 ON AG1.E_ID = AG2.E_ID 
    AND AG1.Fromdate >= AG2.fromdate and AG1.todate <= AG2.todate and AG1.lev < AG2.lev
Order by E_ID, Fromdate
```

Edit 1 : I have fixed the script. Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d0a2/3/0).

Comment: Nice.  To merge items that end and start of the same day too just make the change <= 1 after the datediff.

Comment: Thank you, that's precisely what I need!